# Convert String IP to IPADDRESS Control

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I got the IP address from SQL Server database.
Now i have this IP Address in a 'char'.
But, I want convert the string IP (example: "127.0.0.1")
To the IPADDRESS Control ..
I'm this [PIC HERE](http://gyazo.com/0568a7551db51b89a00577d83537df9d)
How we do that :D ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`InetPton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to convert it to a binary address, that can then be used to set the control.

```
char ip_address_string[] = "127.0.0.1";
DWORD address;

if (LOBYTE(LOWORD(GetVersion())) >= 6)
{
    IN_ADDR address_struct;
    InetPtoN(AF_INET, ip_address_string, &address_struct);

    address = (DWORD) address_struct.S_un.S_long;
}
else
{
    address = (DWORD) inet_addr(ip_address_string);
}
```

Now you can use `address` to initialize the control.

Comment: Ohh, I was just about to recomend [`inet_addr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx) until I noticed that `InetPton` does IPv6 too!

Comment: `InetPton` is also Vista+ only.

Comment: @Deanna Added check for Windows version, uses `inet_addr` if version lower than Vista.

Comment: That's not the correct way. The check is OK, but function imports are resolved at load time (i.e. before runtime). That means XP trips on an unresolved import and doesn't even start your executable.